# Correct way to animate position and size of a UIView with image (this method breaks in Xcode 6)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I have an app where I am simultaneously animating the position and size of a UIView with an image by calling setFrame inside a animateWithDuration, thusly:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: imageName];    
[_faceView setImage: image];
[_faceView setFrame: CGRectMake(-40.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0)];
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [_faceView setFrame: CGRectMake(80.0, 140.0, 160, 160)];
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {}
```

When compiled in Xcode 5, and running in either iOS 7 or iOS 8, I have obtained the correct behaviour using the above methodology.

Now, compiling in Xcode 6 (and hence against SDK 8.0, which I assume is the defining difference?), and running in either iOS 7 or iOS 8, this code does not achieve the correct result: what appears to happen is that the image is animated to its "natural" size rather than to that specified in the CGRect.

So: (a) does anyone know why this might be? and (b) either way, is the basic problem that I'm doing something wrong? -- is there a more "correct" way to achieve an animation of position/size of an image in a UIView that will achieve the desired result?

Comment: can you not just animate the constraints? Or must this explicitly not use auto layout?

Comment: It's not that it must not explicitly, it's just that it's a project that I set up pre Xcode 6 and I'm trying to update some bits to it with minimal effort without having to re-write the entire universe...!

Comment: Here is an [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ara6l7xgfqg3jj2/AnimationTest.zip?dl=0), I created it with Xcode 6 and it works fine.

Comment: I take it there's no flag I can set on a view to say "please exclude this view entirely from auto layout and just put it where I tell you to put it and disregard it when deciding on where to place other views"...?

Comment: I believe you can use `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for that

Answer (score 4):

By default in Xcode6 even if you don't have any constraints associated with a view - IB will create default ones. That's why after setting the frame view is getting repositioned to the original frame.

You can add line

```
_faceView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

And this essentially will break existing constraints, but you will get proper animation.

However I would suggest to re-do this animation to use auto-layout constraints and not use strict frame setting.

Comment: So I used this option and then the animation is correct, but once the animated view moves, it buggers up the positions/sizes of other elements in the view. This is INSANITY!!!! So... how would I use auto-layout constraints to simply move a view around the screen without messing up other stuff?

Comment: If you updated your view with auto-layout constraints, then animation is pretty easy. Just expose needed constraints as outlet (for example distance from the top, and width of a view) and change these constraints inside the animation block.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to begin to use Autolayout to make animation. As I remembered, it has been recommended in the WWDC session.

As a simplest example, if you want to move a view right 40 point in animation , you can add a constraint to the left, use Interface Builder to link it to a `IBOutlet` like

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint;
```

And the animation code like follow:

```
- (IBAction)animatinoButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.leftConstraint.constant = self. leftConstraint.constant + 40.f;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.f animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

The method layoutIfNeeded will force the view to rearrange the subviews immediately, which move the target view and make animation.

I think you can create suitable constraints in your case and make correct animation as well.